# How to change string to date in Java

Tags: java

i need to to convert an string to date format in java i have an string that i get from torrent file

```
the string is like 1278622088
```

Comment: And what do you expect 1278622088 to be converted to?

Comment: @Steve Kuo: wow, just wow... Such a number is a timestamp in seconds given from the Unix epoch (and also widely used outside of the Un*x world, for example it's that kind of timestamp that Java is using).  You definitely want to read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch

Answer (score 6):

That's a timestamp in seconds. You can use the constructor of [`java.util.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29) taking a timestamp in milliseconds. You first need to convert the `String` to `Long` using [`Long#valueOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) and then multiply with `1000`.

```
String timestamp = "1278622088";
Date date = new Date(Long.valueOf(timestamp) * 1000);
```

Comment: By the way, you seem to have another account: http://stackoverflow.com/users/414644/ramesh You should register your account. This way you can keep history of your questions and reputation. Else your unregistered account is tied to a specific computer/webbrowser and will get lost whenever the cookies are cleared. Without an account you cannot anymore edit/comment your own questions nor accept helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a `Long` value to `new Date()`

So as long as you can parse your `String` to a `Long` value, you're ok.